# Overwrite prop of third party component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a prop, `renderIndicator`, for a third party component called `Carousel`.  The below code shows the default code for `renderIndicator`, as found in the source code for the package/component.

```
<Carousel
    ....
    renderIndicator: (
        onClickHandler: (e: React.MouseEvent | React.KeyboardEvent) => void,
        isSelected: boolean,
        index: number,
        label: string
    ) => {
        return (
            <li
                className={klass.DOT(isSelected)}
                onClick={onClickHandler}
                onKeyDown={onClickHandler}
                value={index}
                key={index}
                role="button"
                tabIndex={0}
                aria-label={`${label} ${index + 1}`}
            />
        );
    },
   ....
>
```

My question is, is there a way to elegantly overwrite/pass in a new `onClickHandler` into the function without overwriting the whole function? The default `renderIndicator` component works great, but I just want to give it a new `onClickHandler`. I could copy the whole function, but it just seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new function that calls the passed in `onClickHandler` and does whatever else you need it to do, then pass that as the actual click handler:

```jsx
<Carousel
    ...
    renderIndicator: (
        onClickHandler: (e: React.MouseEvent | React.KeyboardEvent) => void,
        ...
    ) => {
        const customClickHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent | React.KeyboardEvent) => {
            onClickHandler(e)

            someOtherCustomLogic(e)
        }

        return (
            <li
                onClick={customClickHandler}
                onKeyDown={customClickHandler}
                ...
            />
        );
    },
   ...
>
```

Comment: but as you can see, their default props import `klass` in `klass.DOT(isSelected)`, which would require me to import that into my file to duplicate their functionality. It just seems messy to have to rewrite their whole function. Is there really no way to avoid this?

Comment: @ambe5960 Ahh I see, I think I misunderstood what you were asking. No, assuming you're using `react-responsive-carousel`, it seems like the API requires you to re-supply the whole render logic if you want to rewrite one part of it (such as the handler). But you can avoid re-importing `klass` by just copying the `DOT` logic from https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel/blob/48085850ea3317d578f7a7b1c995528cf702445b/src/cssClasses.ts